# How can I use a project source code as a library for an another project?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-library

I am a beginer in android.My client gave me a project source code(using native libraries) as a refference.Is there any possibilities to use these source code as library for my android project? If it is possible,how can I access methods of these library file? any one please help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import the project into work space. Right click on the project in eclipse. Goto properties. Choose Android. Check if Is Library chexk box is ticked. If not tick the same. This is a library project now.

To refer the library project in your android project.

Right click on the project in eclipse. Goto properties. Choose Android. Click add. Browse the library project and add the same.

Clean and build.

For more information check the link

http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html

Information regarding library project

http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html

Comment: i am not sure what kind of library you are using.But the procedure to refer a library project in your android project is as above

Answer (score 0):

If the Android development tools build a project which uses a library project, it also builds the components of the library and adds them to the .apk file of the compiled application.

Therefore a library project can be considered to be a compile-time artifact. A Android library project can contain Java classes, Android components and resources. Only assets are not supported.

To create a library project, set the Mark this project as library flag in the Android project generation wizard.

To use such a library, select the generated project, right-click on it and select properties. On the Android tab add the library project to it.

The library project must declare all its components, e.g. activities, service, etc. via the AndroidManifest.xml file. The application which uses the library must also declare all the used components via the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Other projects can now use this library project. This can also be set via the properties of the corresponding project.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this

To create a library project, set the Mark this project as library flag in the Android project generation wizard.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html